# Downloading a Firebase XLS File to Kotlin-based Android App

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

first time post - long time reader (be nice ;-). Let me assure you I've spent lots of time on stackoverflow finding an answer that addresses my question from "front to back". No luck as of yet. Many googling attempts, blog attempts. Still no luck.

My problem seems so simple; to begin, I've created a Google Firebase bucket that holds a collection of Microsoft Excel files (this is a work requirement).

I have created an Android app (Android Studio) in Kotlin which can read these Excel files and dynamically build a GUI for a survey app used by audiologists. Locally (by loading from Assets) it works great!

But now I am trying (desperately) to download the same XLS files in my work's Firebase bucket and store them locally (forever) on my Android emulator / external device. I don't want to read bytes, I don't want a temp file.  I want a complete local copy of the Excel file on GCP on my phone's Document area. I've tried a ton of things (hacking, blogs, etc). My current code seems like it should work (but given my admittedly limited knowledge of Firebase - no luck).

For this post, assume a simple `<Button>` widget in a `<LinearLayout>`.  When clicked, I just want to connect to my (ready to go) Firebase bucket and download the *entire file forever* on my phone's local storage (not an SD card - but in a subfolder of my Documents storage area; e.g. Files/Documents/Surveys/Survey1.xls). The audiologists need to see the downloaded file from the phone real time to use in research studies.

**The Code Thus Far**

Assume a simple empty activity with a `<Button>`. My `<MainActivity>` has members to capture `FirebaseStorage` and `FirebaseAuth`:

```
private lateinit var storage: FirebaseStorage
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
```

In my

```
onCreate()
```

I initialize things as so:

[Set up creds and storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvpiy.png)

Now, assume I have a "button click" event in my main activity that wants to nab the external file as so:

```
fun btnDownloadBucket_Click(view: View)
    {
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files
        val storageRef = storage.reference.child("Surveys/SurveyOne.txt")
        val rootPath = File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, "Surveys")

        if (!rootPath.exists())
        {
            rootPath.mkdirs()
        }

        val localFile = File(rootPath, "SurveyFour.txt")
        storageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Download Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Internal storage/Surveys/SurveyFour.txt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }.addOnFailureListener{
                Toast.makeText(this, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

    }
```

I fail. The above code is iteration x of N. I've tried so many changes. I always land in the fail toast with the following message:

[Fail!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObusZ.png)

Can any of you in the stackoverflow community please help me answer what I think is an straightforward question:

- How can I build an Android Studio (Kotlin or Java) app which just downloads an MS Excel file (*not* an image file which is all of what the examples show) to a subfolder of my Android's Files area?

If I can just to this, I can build my dynamic UI and all is good.

Thanks in advance, and please guide a n00b on better ways to interact with StackOverflow (but again- let's all be nice).

Cheers!

Comment: PS- I am able to read all files from my bucket and place them in a ListView without problem- the oddball authentication error in the code above seems out of place, since I use the same storage and auth objects in the program.